# Pycharm select all code above the line with the caret

Tags: pycharm

I am looking to select all code above the line with the caret.

"Select All" - Ctrl + A,  will select all code in the script

but how do i select everything above the caret only?.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a macro which executes the following editor actions in succession:

Move Caret to Text End with Selection

Swap Selection boundaries

Move Statement Down.

---

Additionally you can pair this with a couple of "Page Down" commands, to make the original line at caret the topmost line in the editor.
And you can of cause excute the "Run" action in the same macro